# Get information about table partitions

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

I have a partitioned table out of main table using range.

```
CREATE TABLE public.partition1 PARTITION OF public.maintable 
FOR VALUES FROM ('2017-01-01 00:00:00') TO ('2050-01-01 00:00:00')
```

How can i get the Values range information using a query to postgres.

I have used a query that at least gives me information for the main and partitioned tables, but i cannot seem to find a way to access the value range
**FROM ('2017-01-01 00:00:00') TO ('2050-01-01 00:00:00')**
assigned to table partition1

Query used to get partition table information

```
WITH RECURSIVE partition_info
(relid,
 relname,
 relsize,
 relispartition,
 relkind) AS 
 (
    (SELECT oid AS relid,
           relname,
           pg_relation_size(oid) AS relsize,
           relispartition,
           relkind
    FROM pg_catalog.pg_class
    WHERE relname = 'completedorders' AND
      relkind = 'p')

  UNION ALL

    (SELECT
         c.oid AS relid,
         c.relname AS relname,
         pg_relation_size(c.oid) AS relsize,
         c.relispartition AS relispartition,
         c.relkind AS relkind
    FROM partition_info AS p,
         pg_catalog.pg_inherits AS i,
         pg_catalog.pg_class AS c
    WHERE p.relid = i.inhparent AND
         c.oid = i.inhrelid AND
         c.relispartition = true)
  )       
  SELECT * FROM partition_info;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following query provides the information about partitions as well. From there on its just string manipulation in order to get further information. 
**Note**: you will have to change the name of the table in the query.

```
with recursive inh as (
   select i.inhrelid, null::text as parent
   from pg_catalog.pg_inherits i
     join pg_catalog.pg_class cl on i.inhparent = cl.oid
     join pg_catalog.pg_namespace nsp on cl.relnamespace = nsp.oid
   where nsp.nspname = 'public'          ---<< change table schema here
     and cl.relname = 'tablename'   ---<< change table name here
   union all
   select i.inhrelid, (i.inhparent::regclass)::text
   from inh
   join pg_catalog.pg_inherits i on (inh.inhrelid = i.inhparent)
)
select c.relname as partition_name,
        n.nspname as partition_schema,
        pg_get_expr(c.relpartbound, c.oid, true) as partition_expression,
        pg_get_expr(p.partexprs, c.oid, true) as sub_partition,
        parent,
        case p.partstrat
          when 'l' then 'LIST'
          when 'r' then 'RANGE'
        end as sub_partition_strategy
from inh
   join pg_catalog.pg_class c on inh.inhrelid = c.oid
   join pg_catalog.pg_namespace n on c.relnamespace = n.oid
   left join pg_partitioned_table p on p.partrelid = c.oid
order by n.nspname, c.relname
```

Answer (score 1):

Version with parent_schema and only table relkind:

```
with recursive inh as (
   select i.inhrelid, cl.relname as parent,nsp.nspname as  parent_schema
   from pg_catalog.pg_inherits i
     join pg_catalog.pg_class cl on i.inhparent = cl.oid
     join pg_catalog.pg_namespace nsp on cl.relnamespace = nsp.oid
   where nsp.nspname = 'public'          ---<< change table schema here
     and cl.relname = 'tablename'   ---<< change table name here
     and cl.relkind='p'
   union all
   select i.inhrelid, (i.inhparent::regclass)::text,inh.parent_schema
   from inh
   join pg_catalog.pg_inherits i on (inh.inhrelid = i.inhparent)
)
select c.relname as partition_name,
        n.nspname as partition_schema,
        pg_get_expr(c.relpartbound, c.oid, true) as partition_expression,
        pg_get_expr(p.partexprs, c.oid, true) as sub_partition,
        parent,
        parent_schema,
        case p.partstrat
          when 'l' then 'LIST'
          when 'r' then 'RANGE'
        end as sub_partition_strategy
from inh
   join pg_catalog.pg_class c on inh.inhrelid = c.oid
   join pg_catalog.pg_namespace n on c.relnamespace = n.oid
   left join pg_partitioned_table p on p.partrelid = c.oid
order by n.nspname, c.relname
```